# What does the error "Use of undefined constant CRAFT_BUILD - assumed 'CRAFT_BUILD'?" mean?

Tags: admin, error

Accessing my /admin of a craft site and i get this error.

```
Internal Server Error

Use of undefined constant CRAFT_BUILD - assumed 'CRAFT_BUILD'
```

Never happened before today, I'm running PHP v5.6.30.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a plugin installed which had been using CRAFT_BUILD and as its been deprecated it was throwing the error, problem was could access admin to update plugin.

Manually, entered CRAFT_BUILD and other deprecated info into `craft/app/Info.php` and it let me login to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when updating a live Craft site. My local update had gone fine. So I ended up editing my `craft/app/Info.php` file (live) from:

```
define('CRAFT_VERSION', '2.6');
define('CRAFT_BUILD', '2949');
```

to just:

```
define('CRAFT_VERSION', '2.6.2949');
```

I then ran into the error:

> Internal Server Error Use of undefined constant CRAFT_MIN_VERSION_REQUIRED

So again, I updated my `craft/app/Info.php` to add the line:

```
define('CRAFT_MIN_VERSION_REQUIRED', '2.1.2570');
```

It then logged me in and and asked me to finish updating SEOmatic, so I clicked `Update` and it was running fine again but showing the following depreciation errors:

> craft()->getBuild() has been deprecated. As of Craft 2.6.2951,
>   craft()->getVersion() returns the complete version number
>   (X.Y.Z).  /var/www/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (149)